# Service to allow users to upload large files

Tags: php, upload

I need an app/service I can put on our web server (LAMP) that will allow external (and unauthenticated) users to upload large files (10 MB - 100 MB for now) to our website, instead of trying to email them.

If possible, it should be very user-friendly, as it will be used by non-technical users.

I don't really want to roll my own, as I'm sure this must've been done before, but I'm not sure exactly what to search for.  I seem to get a lot of results for torrent servers etc.

Comment: Why don't you do it yourself? it shouldn't be that much work! Sure it had be done a lot of times, but every solution is specific to the environment it is used in. SO give it a try, and if you get stuck ask again.

Comment: Because nothing is as simple as it seems.  If there's a pre-baked solution that handles the uploads, notification, auto-deletion, stats, captcha, fancy ajaxified uploads etc, why shouldn't I try that first?  Creating a PHP form with an upload box is not really the ideal solution, it's just "a solution".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Jens. To help you along, this might help: http://www.plupload.com/

Comment: I've marked this as the correct answer, because although we ended up going with a third-party web-based product, I did download this tool and got a demo running very quickly.  It's a neat solution, and relatively easy to implement.

Comment: What was the 3rd party product you went with, if you can remember?

Answer (score 1):

Try using an app called Simple2FTP that is easy and allows visitors/customers to upload files of virtually any size.  (they say they have successfully uploaded a 1 + gig file using their app)  I think it is simple and pretty flexible enough to allow for a number of different use situations. They are at http://www.Simple2FTP.com and have a free trial you can download.